# Is it possible to change a vertical line in to horizontal when the screen size is reduced?

Tags: html, css

I want to change my vertical line in normal view in to a horizontal line in mobile view.

is it really possible?

Comment: like transform: rotate(90deg)?

Comment: use something like above in conjunction with user agent: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you are drawing your line, but you could use media queries to change the appearance of your line depending on the screen size.

The example below will rotate 90 deg (clockwise) when the screen is smaller than 600 pixels wide.

```css
.line{
  width: 300px;
  height: 3px;
  background: black;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .line{
    transform: rotate(90deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

Comment: why `transform` , `writing-mode` is there to be used too , dedicated to text;)

Comment: Worked fine, Thanks @G-Cyr